# inserting data into SQL Server from vb.net

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I am facing problem trying to insert data into a SQL Server database.

This is the function

```
 Public Sub Processsales()

        Dim cust_guid As Guid = Session("guid")
        Dim Iden As Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid
        Dim ssql As String
        ssql = "Insert into WebSite.wTranH ([WebTranHGUID],[TranType],[LOCTN]) values ([Iden],[2],[5])"

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("SqlConnectionString"))
            Dim command As New SqlCommand(ssql, connection)
            connection.Open()
            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

but its giving these errors

> *Invalid column name 'Iden'.*
>
> *Invalid column name '2'.*
>
> *Invalid column name '5'.*

Any solutions?

Thanks

Comment: remove `[]` from values.
ssql = "Insert into WebSite.wTranH ([WebTranHGUID],[TranType],[LOCTN]) values (Iden,2,5)"

Answer (score 2):

The **best approach** would be to [use a **parametrized query** to avoid SQL injection](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) attacks:

```
Public Sub Processsales()
    Dim cust_guid As Guid = Session("guid")
    Dim Iden As Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid()

    ' define your SQL query and use parameters for the values to be inserted           
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "INSERT INTO WebSite.wTranH([WebTranHGUID], [TranType], [LOCTN]) VALUES (@HGuid, @TranType, @LocTn)"

    Dim connString As String = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("SqlConnectionString")

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connString)
        Using command As New SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection)
            connection.Open()

            ' add paramters and their values to the SqlCommand instance
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HGuid", Iden)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TranType", 2)
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocTn", 5)

            command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            connection.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @user2008654: **WHERE** (on what line) do you get this error? You **do have** a variable `Iden` declared - right??

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
values ('Iden',2 ,5 )
```

instead.

Comment: -1. See, 'Iden' is obviously a variable (declared 2 lines before the string) and you try to insert the name there.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your sql string.
You pass fixed values for `TranType` and `LOCTN` columns, but the `WebTranHGUID` column should get the value of the structure `Iden` not its name. 
Of course the values should be passed without brackets to not confuse with column names.
You should change your code to concatenate the value of Iden to the sql command in this way:

```
Public Sub Processsales()

    Dim cust_guid As Guid = Session("guid")
    Dim Iden As Guid = System.Guid.NewGuid
    Dim ssql As String
    ssql = "Insert into WebSite.wTranH ([WebTranHGUID],[TranType],[LOCTN]) " + 
    "values (" + Iden.ToString + ",2,5)"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(....))
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(ssql, connection)
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using




End Sub
```